# Getting issue After Upgrading Angular from v9 to 16

Tags: angular, webpack

after i upgrade my angular project from v9 to v16 a lot of issues happened:
first when use ng serve to run the project this warning appear
Warning: Unable to locate stylesheet: D:\DevOps_\Nada\Nada\Dev\Sky.Nada.DesignPortal\ClientApp\assets\Styles\glyphicons.min.css

this appear for all links in my index.html although is use    in index.html

-- and the webpack folder stop appearing in the browser debugging  tool in source tab

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ClientApp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "strict": false,
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "angular-slickgrid",
              "stream",
              "qrcode",
              "lodash",
              "style-dictionary",
              "jszip",
              "devexpress-diagram",
              "devexpress-gantt",
              "devextreme-quill",
              "jsbarcode",
              "crypto-js",
              "secure-web-storage",
              "jquery",
              "xml2js",
              "pdfjs-dist",
              "file-saver",
              "exceljs",
              "devextreme-dist"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist/ClientApp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "src/polyfills.ts"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/Styles/fontawesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/Styles/font-awesome.min.css",
              "node_modules/stimulsoft-reports-js/Css/stimulsoft.designer.office2013.whiteblue.css",
              "node_modules/stimulsoft-reports-js/Css/stimulsoft.viewer.office2013.whiteblue.css",
              "node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui-angular/theme.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/stimulsoft-reports-js/Scripts/stimulsoft.reports.js",
              "node_modules/stimulsoft-reports-js/Scripts/stimulsoft.viewer.js",
              "node_modules/stimulsoft-reports-js/Scripts/stimulsoft.designer.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/aws-exports-dev.ts",
                  "with": "src/aws-exports-prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "30mb",
                  "maximumError": "30mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/aws-exports-dev.ts",
                  "with": "src/aws-exports-test.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "30mb",
                  "maximumError": "30mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }

              ]
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": false,
              "devtool": "source-map",
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "30mb",
                  "maximumError": "30mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }

              ]
            },
            "local": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "30mb",
                  "maximumError": "30mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:prod"
            },
            "test": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:test"
            },
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:dev"

            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "budgets": []
            },
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:local",
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "budgets": []

            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css",
              "node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/Styles/fontawesome.min.css",
              "src/assets/Styles/font-awesome.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve:prod"
            },
            "test": {
              "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve:test"
            },
            "dev": {
              "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve:dev"
            },

            "local": {
              "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve:local"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}



tsconfig.json (note that when I update  "target" to "ES2022" error appear that this value not valid value)

{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "types": [
      "jquery",
      "node"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "stream": [ "node_modules/stream-browserify" ]
    }
  },
  "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
    "angular-slickgrid",
    "stream"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "static",
    "lib"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ]
}


packages.json

{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "22.5.0",
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=14192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration=dev",
    "build-prod-patch": "npm version patch && node ./replace.build.js && ng build --configuration=dev  && node ./versioning.build.js",
    "build-prod-no-patch": "node ./replace.build.js && ng build --configuration=dev  && node ./versioning.build.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "15.0.0-beta.42",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^5.0.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.23.8",
    "@floating-ui/dom": "^1.5.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "angular-code-input": "2.0.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.0.12",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "core-js": "3.6.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "devextreme": "23.1.7",
    "devextreme-angular": "23.1.7",
    "devextreme-aspnet-data-nojquery": "2.6.1",
    "devextreme-dist": "23.1.7",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsbarcode": "^3.11.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.13",
    "ngx-barcode6": "^1.0.13",
    "ngx-device-detector": "6.0.2",
    "pdfjs": "^2.4.7",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.5.207",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.3.5",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "secure-web-storage": "^1.0.2",
    "stimulsoft-reports-js": "^2023.3.2",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.27",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.14",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you followed this https://update.angular.io/?v=9.0-16.0 as step by step process regarding the info `Warning: Be sure to follow the guide below to migrate your application to the new version. You can't run ng update to update Angular applications more than one major version at a time. `?

Comment: yah i follow the step and update the versions one by one

Comment: If there any thing can do it to fix the project?